# Dynamic Json values in Play Framework Json

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am currently using the Play framework json parser in order to parse a json string in my scala code.

I have the following class:

```
case class Address(address: String,
                   gps: GPS,
                   country: String) {}

object Address {    
  implicit val reads: Reads[Address] = (
      (JsPath \ "address").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "gps").read[GPS] and
      (JsPath \ "country").read[String]
    ) (Address.apply _)

  implicit val writes: Writes[Address] = (
      (JsPath \ "address").write[String] and
      (JsPath \ "gps").write[GPS] and
      (JsPath \ "country").write[String]
    ) (unlift(Address.unapply))
}
```

Which works fine with the following json:

```
{
    "address": "123 Fake Street",
    "country": "USA",
    "gps": { ... }
}
```

The problem is that in some situations the json may instead have the gps field be a string which doesnt parse, i.e.

```
{
    "address": "123 Fake Street",
    "country": "USA",
    "gps": "123abc"
}
```

Now I know that I cant have the gps member be both a string or a GPS object, but is there any way to have it be say an Option[GPS] and only have a value if the json contained a gps object?

Comment: not really understaning your question, but I wrote a post on play-json and it may help you on solving your problems: http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-json/ and http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-json-part2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only very little is needed to be changed in your impl. 
You need to read the field "gps" as something that is 'safe' like JsValue and then try to map it into your GPS case class if it can be done, if not, return None.

```
case class GPS(a:String, b:String)
object GPS {
  val travelInfoReads = Json.reads[GPS]
  val travelInfoWrites = Json.writes[GPS]
  implicit val travelInfoFormat: Format[GPS] = Format(travelInfoReads, travelInfoWrites)
}
case class Address(address: String,
                   gps: Option[GPS],
                   country: String) {}

object Address {
  implicit val reads: Reads[Address] = (
    (JsPath \ "address").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "gps").read[JsValue].map(js => js.asOpt[GPS]) and
      (JsPath \ "country").read[String]
    ) (Address.apply _)

  implicit val writes: Writes[Address] = (
    (JsPath \ "address").write[String] and
      (JsPath \ "gps").writeNullable[GPS] and
      (JsPath \ "country").write[String]
    ) (unlift(Address.unapply))
}
```

I also tested it:

```
val json = Json.toJson(Address("1",Some(GPS("a","b")),"2"))
      println(json)
      println(json.as[Address])
      val newObj: JsObject = (json.as[JsObject] - "gps") + ("gps" -> JsNumber(1))
      println(newObj)
      val a = newObj.as[Address]
      println(a)
      a must beEqualTo(Address("1",None,"2"))
```

Output was like

```
{"address":"1","gps":{"a":"a","b":"b"},"country":"2"}
Address(1,Some(GPS(a,b)),2)
{"address":"1","country":"2","gps":1}
Address(1,None,2)
```

Comment: Wow, that works great! However, I tried your tested example: `val newObj: JsObject = (json.as[JsObject] - "gps") + ("gps" -> JsNumber(1))` and while this works in the example, in my case my json is such like {address:{ gps:{...} }}, do you know if there is anyway to inject it into the inner element?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you write more jsons as example?

Comment: I was meaning if instead of `{
    "address": "123 Fake Street",
    "country": "USA",
    "gps": { ... }
}` the json was actually: `{ "address": {
    "address": "123 Fake Street",
    "country": "USA",
    "gps": { ... } 
  }
}` but I realised I could do: `val gps: JsObject = Json.parse("""{"address":{ "gps":{...} }}""").as[JsObject]; val json = Json.parse(address.toJson()).as[JsObject].deepMerge(gps)`

Comment: However I have an issue if the json is: `{ "addresses": [ { "address": "123 Fake Street", "country": "USA" }, { "address": "123 Fake Street", "country": "USA" } }` because doing a deep merge with say `{ "addresses": [ { "gps": {...} }, { "gps": {...} } }` doesnt merge the arrays, but rather overites them

Comment: Managed to get it working by frankensteining a new json object out of the old ones, thanks for your help!

Comment: (JsPath \ "gps").read[JsValue].map(js => js.asOpt[GPS]) may be simple (JsPath \ "gps").readNullable[GPS]

Comment: @andrey.ladniy well, the most obvious thing, but I forgot to try it :D , I thought that it only works when the field is completely missing not when it is different type. e.g. it is Integer instead of JsObject.

Comment: @JurajPetrovic yes, you are right about unparsed types.